# Probability question - throwing dice

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Let's say that we have 2 fair dice and we throw them at the same time. If I want to describe the probability filed will the event (1,2) be the same with (2,1)?
By event (x,y) I mean that the first dice shows x and the second y.

Comment: If you throw the dice at the same time, what do you mean by "the _first_ die shows $x$"?

Answer (score 5):

If we coloured the dice one red and the other blue then the probability that the red has 1 and the blue has 2 is $\frac{1}{36}$.

Similarly if we wanted the blue to have 1 and the red 2 the probability is $\frac{1}{36}$.

As these events are mutually exclusive the probability of getting 1 or 2 regardless of which die they are on is $\frac{2}{36}$

Comment: If they had the same color, then what it the probability of getting 1 or 2?

Comment: Regardless of colour is $\frac{2}{36}$

Comment: Ok. But then what is the difference with picking a ball from a bag. If we have 2 red balls and 4 blue, then one will calculate the probability of picking a red balls using combinations and not arrangements.

Comment: How many balls are you selecting? Are you replacing the balls?

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. There are 5 red balls and 4 blue, and I want to select 3 red balls.